# How to send a notification to multiple subscribers using web-push package of Node.js?

Tags: node.js, push-notification, web-push

How we can send a notification to multiple subscribers using web-push package of Node.js?

We can loop through for list of subscribers but it won't be scalable for millions of subscribers.

Example:

```
for(var myKey in subData) {
    endp   =  subData[myKey]['ENDPOINT'];
    enckey =  subData[myKey]['ENCKEY'];
    webPush.sendNotification(endp, 200, enckey, JSON.stringify({
        title: 'Test Title',
        msg: 'Test Notification',
     }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Web Push standard currently doesn't support sending a notification to multiple subscribers.

Indeed, the key is related to a specific user. If all users shared the same key, the encrypted data would be readable by others. Read [[1](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/webpush/current/msg00261.html)] for a more thorough explanation.

I'd suggest implementing a solution that sends notifications in batches, waiting a little between the batches. Usually the notifications don't have to be real-time, so this is usually feasible.