# How to send a notification to multiple firefox devices at a time

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, web-push

Anyone know how to send the notification to multiple Firefox devices in one POST call.

Answer (score 2):

The [Web Push standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-webpush-protocol-02) currently doesn't allow it. Take a look at [this discussion](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/webpush/current/msg00261.html) for more information.

[How to send a notification to multiple subscribers using web-push package of Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332632/how-to-send-a-notification-to-multiple-subscribers-using-web-push-package-of-nod) contains a possible alternative solution (the question is more specific than this one, but you could apply the same solution).