# Web Push Notification, how to Post with multiple UAIDs without using loop?

Tags: java, push-notification, web-push

**How do we post to web push endpoints with multiple UAIDs in the url**

> UAID goes in the end of the URL

I am posting to this URL with single UAID with the below code, which is working fine : "https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/push/v1/-----UAID goes here-----"
But how do I do it with multiple UAIDs?

```
URL url = new URL("https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/push/v1/-----UAID goes here-----");
           HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
           urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

       urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");


       urlConnection.setRequestProperty("content-encoding", "aesgcm128");
       urlConnection.setRequestProperty("ttl", "60");
       urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
       urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
       final OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

       outputStream.flush();
       outputStream.close();
       if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 201) {
           String result = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
           System.out.println("PUSH OK: " + result);
       } else {
           InputStream errorStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
           String error = readStream(errorStream);
           System.out.println("PUSH" + "Not OK: " + error);
       }
```

Comment: Currently the specs don't provide a way to reach multiple endpoints at once. You have to send a POST for each endpoint

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a notification to multiple firefox devices at a time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133772/how-to-send-a-notification-to-multiple-firefox-devices-at-a-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing because in Chrome it allows you to send multiple registration ids. Unfortunately, it seems that this is not available yet in Mozilla Push Notification.

Comment: N.B.: It isn't "Mozilla Push Notifications", this is the Web Push standard that also Chrome will adopt soon.

Comment: But Chrome Notification allow us to send multiple registration ids.

Comment: How we can send multiple registration ids in chrome ?

Comment: I think this might help you https://github.com/web-push-libs/webpush-java

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a push message with a payload, you have to use a loop for Chrome (FCM/GCM) too. Because according to the Push API specification, payload have to be encrypted with an ***asymmetric*** public key, which is unique for each of your clients (User Agent). For more information, see following links:

1. [Push API specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/)
2. [Message Encryption for Web Push](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-thomson-webpush-encryption)
3. [Web Push Payload Encryption](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/web-push-encryption)